# Problema al recorrer array en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema cuando quiero recorrer mi array en C, y es que el codigo solo avanza cierta cantidad de numeros, aqui les dejo el codigo y una explicacion mas detallada

```
int main()
{
int i=0, k=0, cant, num[i];

printf("Escriba cuanta cantidad de numeros quiere -> ");
scanf("%d", &cant);

for (i=0; i<=cant; i++){

    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<cant; i++){
    printf("%d", num[i]);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Es un código bastante simple, lo primero que hace el código es pedirle al usuario que introduzca un numero que se va a guardar en la variable *cant*, luego de eso, pide que introduzcas números, esto dentro de un bucle for que recorre desde la posición 0 hasta el numero que se haya introducido, el problema esta aquí, si ponemos por ejemplo "2" en la cantidad, el código funciona sin problemas, pero al poner por ejemplo 7, solo me pide cargar 3 números o 4, no se donde esta el problema.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Cuando creas `num` le das un tamaño de `i`, que en este caso seria de `0`. Eso significa que cuando vas escribiendo en el array mas adelante, estas escribiendo en memoria que no tienes asignada para ti. Lo mas probable es que luego de que *"solo me pide cargar 3 números o 4"*, tengas un segfault por escribir en memoria que no es tuya.

Answer (score 2):

En ese programa hay varias fallas:

**1.** Estás declarando un *array* de `0` elementos, esto quiere decir que no hay memoria asignada para el *array*, por lo que es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) (esto indica que tu programa puede funcionar o puede que no) intentar escribir (*o leer*) datos en ese *array*.

Por ejemplo:

```c
int i=0, k=0, cant;
int num[i];
printf("Num: %d", *(num + 1000));
```

En ese ejemplo posiblemente pase dos cosas:

- Si la dirección de memoria está asignada al proceso actual (es decir, tu programa en ejecución), esto daría como resultado un **contenido basura** (caracteres extraños por así decirlo).
- Si la dirección de memoria no está asignada al proceso actual, probablemente el proceso aborte. Hoy en día los sistemas operativos modernos no dejan leer ubicaciones de memoria de otros procesos por cuestión de seguridad (imagínate que el programa pueda leer la dirección y después escribe en ella, sería un caos), así que el SO se encargaría de matar el proceso actual.

Así mismo pasaría si intentas escribir un dato en el array:

```c
int i=0, k=0, cant;
int num[i];
*(num + 1000) = 34444;
printf("Num: %d", *(num + 1000));
```

Aquí corres el riesgo de escribir en una dirección de memoria no asignada al proceso actual, el SO mataría el proceso. Peor aún, si esa ubicación si estuviera asignada al proceso, **estarías sobrescribiendo la memoria del programa.** ¡Fatal!

Por cierto, esta línea:

```c
int num[i];
```

Es un [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-Length Array). No lo deberías usar en C, a partir de [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) los VLA son opcionales, esto quiere decir que dependerá del compilador si lo implementa o no. Así que por cuestión de portabilidad no lo uses. También los VLAs son propensos a que ocurra [stackoverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

**2.** Para recorrer un *array* en C, se empieza desde el índice `0` y se termina en `N - 1`. Donde `N` es el tamaño del *array* (en este caso `N` sería la variable `cant`).

Esto es incorrecto:

```c
for (i=0; i<=cant; i++)
```

Aquí lo único que provocas es que ocurra un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

Lo correcto sería:

```c
for (i=0; i < cant; i++)
```

Ahora, la **solución** al primer *item* de esta respuesta, es usar la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). ¡No le tengas miedo a esta función! ¡No es tan difícil de usar!

El código quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, free */
 
int main()
{
    int i=0, k=0, cant;

    printf("Escriba cuanta cantidad de numeros quiere -> ");
    scanf("%d", &cant);
    //Reservamos memoria para el array.
    int* num = malloc(sizeof(int) * cant);
    if(num == NULL)
    {
        printf("No se pudo reservar memoria!");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (i=0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", num[i]);
    }

    free(num); //Hay que liberar la memoria.
    return 0;
}
```

**Curiosidad:** En el [próximo estándar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) de C, quieren volver a incluir los VLAs.